# cocoa pod install error while want to install afnetworking pod

Tags: ios, afnetworking, cocoapods

```
$ pod install

Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies

[!] Unable to find the Xcode project 
`~/Desktop/TestAfnetwork.xcodeproj` for the target `Pods`.
```

When i run install command then i got this issue.Please solve my problem. I have already updated this setup.

Comment: locate your .xcodeproj path in side your project folder and then try using pod install command.

Comment: In my pod file path are:-source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.5'
xcodeproj '/Users/vallesoft/Desktop/TestAfnetwork.xcodeproj'

Comment: on terminal just write .... cd /Desktop/TestAfnetwork.xcodeproj  path of your project folder where .xcodeproj file is present  and then write pod install

Comment: it gives this,Although my project on desktop :-ValleSofts-Mac-mini:~ vallesoft$ cd /Desktop/TestAfnetwork.xcodeproj
-bash: cd: /Desktop/TestAfnetwork.xcodeproj: No such file or directory

Comment: what is your project folder name ? go setp by step 
will you tell me what is your project folder name and confirm that your .xcodeproj file is seen when you click on that folder

Comment: TestAfnetwork....my folder name and after that we just jump to see xcodeproj

Comment: /Users/vallesoft/Desktop/TestAfnetwork..Full path of my folder

Comment: ok so according to your information you need to do cd /Desktop/TestAfnetwork/TestAfnetwork.xcodeproject also if you will add some screen shot then it will be helpful.

Comment: @nik--ValleSofts-Mac-mini:~ vallesoft$ cd /Desktop/TestAfnetwork/TestAfnetwork.xcodeproject
-bash: cd: /Desktop/TestAfnetwork/TestAfnetwork.xcodeproject: No such file or directory

Comment: @Nik-My pod install but in my folder no workspace show to open this..

Comment: it will be good if you add some screenshots so i will know more about it.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, you should cd to your path /Users/vallesoft/Desktop/TestAfnetwork by using Terminal.
Secondly, type pod init to create Pod file
Finally, make sure that your Pod file look like this

target 'TestAfnetwork' do

pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.6'

end

Good luck